# Weird array conversion into boolean

Tags: php

I place this question, because I have a weird conversion of an array into boolean and I don't really know what's wrong with that.

I have checked my code very carefully, and I don't find any issue that can modify my code.

Do you see something wrong ? And if so, can you help me please ?

So, as requested I am going to explain in more details my problem.

So, I have this class, and I have a method called `load_configuration()` that loading some php files, returning an array of values each.

The array, returned by those files, are stored in equivalent property in the class.

Inside the `load_configuration()` method, I do a `var_dump`, for my class properties `fields` and `settings`, and I get the following result:

```
array (size=1)
  'text' => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
      'label' => string 'Hello world! goes here.' (length=23)
      'default' => string 'Hello world!' (length=12)
```

Also, I have create an array at the end of the method `load_configuration()` and I return the arrays.

Then when I try to use the either the method properties or the returned values from the method `load_configuration()` I get the following with `var_dump()`

```
// In case of the returned array
array (size=2)
  'fields' => boolean true
  'settings' => boolean true

// In case of the class property
boolean true
```

But I don't see the reason. This is a very weird modification.

*For better understanding look the comments in methods `load_configuration()` and `get_template_variables()`*

```
class SS24_Widget extends \SiteOrigin_Widget {
    protected $config_folder = 'Config';
    protected $form_settings = 'settings';
    protected $form_fields = 'fields';
    protected $fields = array();
    protected $settings = array();

    public function __construct( $unique_widget_id = '', $widget_name = '' ) {

        if ( empty( $unique_widget_id ) ) {
            $unique_widget_id = uniqid( 'widget-' );
        }

        $this->load_configuration();

        parent::__construct(
            $unique_widget_id, // The unique id for your widget.
            $widget_name,      // The name of the widget for display purposes.
            $this->settings,   // The widget settings.
            array(),           // The $control_options array, which is passed through to WP_Widget.
            $this->fields,     // The widget fields.
            $this->get_dir() . '/'  // The $base_folder path string.
        );
    }

    protected function load_configuration() {

        $config_files = $this->get_dir() . '/' . $this->config_folder . '/*.php';

        $fields = array();
        $settings = array();

        foreach ( glob( $config_files ) as $file ) {
            switch( basename( $file, '.php' ) ) {
                case $this->form_settings:
                    $this->settings = $this->{$this->form_settings} = require_once $file;
                    $settings = $this->settings;
                    break;
                case $this->form_fields:
                    $this->fields = $this->{$this->form_fields} = require_once $file;
                    $fields = $this->fields;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // This print out the following:
        // array (size=1)
        //  'text' => 
        //    array (size=3)
        //      'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
        //      'label' => string 'Hello world! goes here.' (length=23)
        //      'default' => string 'Hello world!' (length=12)
        var_dump($fields);

        return array(
            'fields'   => $fields,
            'settings' => $this->settings,
        );
    }

    // ...

    public function get_template_variables( $instance, $args ){

        $c = $this->load_configuration();

        // While the following printint out the following:
        // array (size=2)
        //  'fields' => boolean true
        //  'settings' => boolean true
        //
        // boolean true
        var_dump($c);
        echo "<br />";
        var_dump($this->fields);

        return $variables;
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain me what possibly it's wrong with this code ?

**UPDATE #1**
I found that the parent class has a protected member property named `$fields` so in my local code I have change now the variable into a `fields_settings`, but still is converted into `boolean`.

Comment: Is it possible to explain the reason why you have downvote ?

Comment: what is your problem? I mean why do you ask the question, what do you expect to get with this code and what do you get instead? Posting a block of code and asking "what do you think about it" is very hard to answer. For that you can use the php interpreter :)

Comment: Did you read the comments above my code ? And also did you review the code ? If you carefully read it, then you will see what is the question and the problem.

Comment: I find your post a little confusing, could you simplify it a little bit and be more specific about where the error is?

Comment: Ok, I am going to write down what is the problem if that's your problem :)

Comment: People don't like to read big blocks of code. If you break it apart and make the comment a part of your post instead of code comments it would help

Comment: What does the parent constructor do

Comment: @Gavriel I hope now you feel better with the modification.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP the class source code is here : https://github.com/siteorigin/so-widgets-bundle/blob/develop/base/siteorigin-widget.class.php and it is adding extra functionality in the default `WP_Widget` class of the `WordPress`.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: $this->fields = $this->{$this->form_fields} = require_once $file; This means: 1. $var = require_once $file; I don't know what you expect to get in $var, but I'm not surprised if it's gonna be a boolean with true in case it successfully required the file or if it is actually required here (because it wasn't required before yet). Whatever will be $var (true or false) as a 2nd step you assign it to $this->fields, that's why you see true IMHO

Comment: your load_configuration is probably supposed to be a method (that changes the inner state of your object) and not a function (that returns a value). It's kind of a mixture of both. You also use both $fields and $this->fields. I don't see why. It looks like it would be best to only use $this->fields, and not to return anything in load_configuration. This way it would for sure do what you intend to. (Optionally, although I don't recommend you could also do: $x=load_configuration();parent::construct(...,$x['fields'],...))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require_once` is very similar to `include_once`.

If a file has already been included, they will both return boolean **TRUE**.

Quoting [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php):

> If the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns **TRUE**. As the name suggests, the file will be included just once.

Documentation of `require_once` points to `include_once`. This is why the block mentions the former.

To solve your problem, make sure you use `require` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you execute `load_configuration()` in the constructor, so the `require_once` statement returns the correct values here. In the next call to `load_configuration()`, the `require_once` statement returns boolean "true", indicating that the file was already included.

Use require instead of require_once.